# Dropdown menu hidden inside kendogrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-grid, css-position

In my **kendogrid** I need to show a **dropdown menu** (on button click) and **allow column resizing**, showing a scroll bar if my data is too big for the grid. I'm having problems with overflow settings.

Live Sample
http://jsbin.com/gayibo/4/edit?css,output

---

If I set `overflow-y: scroll` on my grid, the dropdown menu is not always visible.
[image]

---

On the other hand, if I set `overflow-y: visible`, I see overflowing rows on the right.
[image]

I've tried everything, every possible overflow combination, changing z-indexes, showing the yellow div on top of my excess row data. Nothing worked.

I also tried changing the dropdown menu to `position: fixed` but it gives problems when you are scrolling the window for any reason (because then the menu is not showing right under the button)

[image: menu position : fixed]
*eg: Fixed positioning of menu*

Browser: Chrome / Firefox (ff requires more resizing to get the same effect)

Twitter-Bootstrap: 2.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a lot of different solutions but in the end I chose to use a `context-menu plugin`, bootstrap themed, binding it to my button click. I'll post a sample code, hoping it will be useful for others in the same situation.

This is the context-menu plugin I'm using: https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu

It involves a little bit of coding and a plugin but I find that the result is truly excellent for my (visual) needs.

Here's the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/lakeliwipo/2/edit)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have also experienced this in the past with a slightly different scenario. Kendo Grid's own data validation messages would be hidden when validating the last row.

There doesn't seem to be a proper way to fix this without things getting messy, but if you are okay with this hack, you can use this code.

```js
     $('#grid').on('click', '.btn.btn-mini.dropdown-toggle',function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
          var gridSpace = $('.k-grid-content');
          gridSpace.animate({scrollTop:500});
        },50);
      });
```

All I'm doing is simply scrolling to the bottom whenever I click on one of your custom grid buttons.

- `500` is an arbitrary height that is bigger than the kendo grid content div and the dropdown height combined.
- `setTimeout` is there to execute the scrolling after the scrollbar is created.

If the dropdown doesn't cause the creation of a scrollbar, that means no dropdown is hidden, and scrollTop does nothing because there is no scrollbar. If a dropdown does invoke the creation of a scrollbar, then it means it is hidden and it is okay to scroll to the very bottom.

Your updated [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wipocutedo/2/edit?js,output)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had tried something similar but it felt too hacky. Also it was difficult to define an arbitrary height like 500 because my menu content is dynamic. I ended up using a plugin, I'll add it as an answer